# typescript module augmentation breaking existing types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add some missing types to this this [transformation-matrix](https://github.com/chrvadala/transformation-matrix/blob/master/transformation-matrix.d.ts).

I have mapped my paths in the `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
"paths": {
  "src/*": ["src/*"],
  "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*", "./types/*"]
}
```

And I have a `types/transformation-matrix.d.ts` that looks like this:

```
import * as tm from 'transformation-matrix';

declare module 'transformation-matrix' {
   export function fromDefinition(...definitionOrArrayOfDefinition: tm.Matrix[]): tm.Matix[];

   export function fromTransformAttribute(transformString: string): rm.Matrix[];
}
```

I can not reference these in my imports:

```
import { fromTransformAttribute, fromDefinition } from 'transformation-matrix';  // all good
import { compose } from 'transformation-matrix/compose';  // now broken
import { Matrix, Point } from 'transformation-matrix';  // now broken
```

From reading the docs, I would have thought the first line:

`import * as tm from 'transformation-matrix';`

Would have brought in the existing types.

Is it because I am using "paths" wrongly and if so, how should I map the file?

Comment: What happens if you just remove this line? I'm not sure if this is the case, but seeing `import` and `declare` in the same file (save purely declaration imports, like `type X = import('x').X`), looks definitely wrong.

Comment: If I remove the import, it is still broke.  I think this is because I am using paths and it is looking here for the full definition.  I probably need to not have this file somewhere different for augmentation